# Netlify images are not showing (React)

Tags: reactjs, web, bootstrap-4, netlify, codesandbox

I deployed a site with react and it does not show all of the images.
I used js to import all the images

```
import productImg1 from "./images/products/product-1.jpg";
import productImg2 from "./images/products/product-2.jpg";
import productImg3 from "./images/products/product-3.jpg";
import productImg4 from "./images/products/product-4.jpg";
import productImg5 from "./images/products/product-5.jpg";
import productImg6 from "./images/products/product-6.jpg";
import productImg7 from "./images/products/product-7.jpg";
import productImg8 from "./images/products/product-8.jpg";
import productImg9 from "./images/products/product-9.jpg";

export default [
  productImg1,
  productImg2,
  productImg3,
  productImg4,
  productImg5,
  productImg6,
  productImg7,
  productImg8,
  productImg9
];
```

And added the images like this

```
import product from "../images";

 <img class="feature-image" src={product[3]} alt="" />
```

or

```
import Logo from "../images/logos/logo_square-removebg-preview.png";

   <img class="logo-image" src={Logo} alt="Beachside bakery logo" />
```

it works fine on codesandbox but it wouldn't on netlify. How do I fix this?

github :  https://github.com/gleny4001/beachside-bakery

codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gleny4001/beachside-bakery

netlify : https://beachside-bakery.netlify.app/

Comment: Did you see the error message?  `Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /src/images/products/product-1.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.`  It even has a suggestion about how to fix the problem.  Did you try that suggestion? Did it work?

Comment: Yes it did and now it wouldn't show the images